# php acces to properties of a containing object

Tags: php, oop, object, scope, this

I have a little problem. In javascript it's possible to forward scope:

```
var aaa = new function () {
    that = this;
    that.bbb  = 'foo';
    this.ccc = new function () {
        this.ddd = 'bar';
        this.eee = function () {
            return that.bbb+this.ddd;
        }
    }
}
```

aaa.ccc.eee() will return 'foobar'. 
How can I do something with the same effect in PHP? I have a code:

```
class bbb {
    public $ccc = 'bar';
        function __construct () {
            echo($that->aaa.$this->ccc);
        }
}
class aaa {
    public $that;
    public $aaa = 'foo';
    public $bbb;
    function __construct () {
        echo($this->aaa);
        $this->$bbb = new bbb();
        $this->$that = $this;
    }
}
$a = new aaa ();
```

Have I to use something like that:

```
$this->bbb = new bbb ($this);

class bbb {
    public $that;
    function __contruct ($parent) {
        $that = $parent
        ....
    }
}
```

?

Comment: You should probably start with http://php.net/oop first

Comment: While they are in some places syntactically similar, it is a *BIG* mistake to compare Javascript to PHP, they are totally different beasts. Javascript is a classless OO language, PHP is a scripting language that provides *some, very limited* OO support. The Javascript code you show creates 2 anonymous objects in a way it is just not possible to do in PHP. It is possible to *pretend* that scope is inheritable with closures, but you need to name the variables you want to inherit when declaring the function and actually all it is doing is passing them into an object by reference.

Comment: @DaveRandom there is nothing similar about these (syntactically or otherwise), PHP's classes are closest to prototypes in js and PHP's closures are closest to this js monstrosity

Comment: @Esailija I meant Javascript and PHP in general are syntactically similar in some places, not that the two code samples above are. Certainly the above Javascript is an odd way to go about things, what's wrong with object literals I wonder?

Comment: @DaveRandom ah I got you wrong, I thought you were talking about these pieces.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing is stopping you from doing the exact same thing as your JS code does, although this is not something you see every day in PHP:

### PHP 5.3

```
$aaa = (object)array(
    'bbb' => 'foo',
    'ccc' => (object) array(
        'ddd' => 'bar',
        'eee' => function() use(&$aaa){ $self = $aaa->ccc; return $aaa->bbb.$self->ddd; }
    ),
);

echo call_user_func($aaa->ccc->eee);
```

Note that in PHP 5.3 it is not possible to use the variable `$this` inside a closure, so you have to get to the requisite context starting from one of the imported variables (in this case `$aaa`).

Also, note that you *cannot* call the function "directly" with `$aaa-ccc->eee()` because PHP sucks: `$aaa->ccc` is an object of type `stdClass` and that class does not have a formal member named `eee`.

I 'm also being "cute" here by capturing `$aaa` by reference, which enables defining the whole object graph in one line (if capturing by value `$aaa` would need to be defined without the closure in one statement, then the closure added with `$aaa->ccc->eee = function() ...` in another).

### PHP 5.4

```
$aaa = (object)array(
    'bbb' => 'foo',
    'ccc' => (object) array(
        'ddd' => 'bar',
        'eee' => function() use(&$aaa) { return $aaa->bbb.$this->ddd; }
    ),
);

$aaa->ccc->eee = $aaa->ccc->eee->bindTo($aaa->ccc);
echo call_user_func($aaa->ccc->eee);
```

In PHP 5.4 it is possible to use `$this` inside a closure as long as you "rebind" it with `bindTo` first. Which you cannot do at the same time as you define the closure for the same reason mentioned earlier: PHP sucks.

Comment: Man it sucks that you can't call anonymous functions assigned to object properties directly. I really hoped that would be sorted out in 5.4, I have one class that I use *a lot* that I really want a to have a method called `list()`, and I can't do it because `list()` is a language construct. Creating an anonymous function in the constructor would be the obvious work around, but it doesn't work (!!!) - so annoying.

Comment: @DaveRandom you could always extend those objects from a class that defines a magical `__call` method that handles it.

Comment: @DaveRandom: I was going to give you Esailija's reply but he beat me to it :) Unfortunately, if you do that you cannot use the `(object)` cast trick because that always casts to `stdClass`.

Comment: *<facepalm>* D'you know, I wrote a class that used `__call()` *yesterday* and I never made that leap. You won't see me for 10 minutes while I go and do that thing I have been annoyed I couldn't do for 2 years. Although I still think it's stupid that you can't do it.

Comment: @Esailija: +1 because why not :)

Comment: @DaveRandom: Unfortunately you have to be **ultra careful** with that `__call` implementation. Testing with `is_callable` can yield [false positives](http://codepad.viper-7.com/vWyrGl), and to prevent these you need to [grovel into PHP's internal implementation](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.11/framework/base/CComponent.php#L264) (class `Closure` and such).

Comment: @Jon If you `call_user_func_array()`, that's not actually a false positive: http://codepad.viper-7.com/867cdd

Comment: @DaveRandom: The false positive is that the value `"trim"` is not a closure. Calling closures with `$foo->bar()` is one thing, but what if `bar` is a string or an array that by chance looks callable? Normally you wouldn't write parens after such, but imagine the hair-pulling it can lead to.

Comment: @Jon True it isn't a closure, but it *is* technically callable. I suppose if you want to restrict this a quick `is_object()`/`instanceof Closure` will sort it out, but in my specific use case it doesn't matter because I have just made my previous method `parsedList()` private and made a rigidly defined `__call()` that only maps `list()` to `parsedList()` (since the class works exactly as I want it to in every other respect) and throws an exception if you try and call anything else.

Comment: @DaveRandom: Sure. I just wanted to point out that you probably would not want to allow calling a string as a function through `__call` by default.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing in javascript is completely different to what you are doing in PHP. In javascript, you are doing closures and in PHP you are doing some very malformed classes.

In PHP, the closest equivalent would be (although ugly because of no IIFE etc)

```
$tmp = function() {
    $that = new stdClass();
    $that->bbb = "foo";

    $tmp = function() use ($that) {
        $this_ = new stdClass();
        $this_->ddd = "bar";
        $this_->eee = function() use ($that, $this_) {
            return $that->bbb . $this_->ddd;
        };
        return $this_;
    };
    $that->ccc = $tmp();
    return $that;
};

$aaa = $tmp();

var_dump( call_user_func( $aaa->ccc->eee ));
//string(6) "foobar"
```

Tested in php 5.4.5.

Answer (score 0):

```
class bbb {
    function __construct ($parrent) {
        echo $parrent->ccc;
    }
}

class aaa {
    public $aaa = 'foo';
    public $bbb;
    public $ccc = 'bar';

    function __construct () {
        echo $this->aaa;
        $this->bbb = new bbb($this);
    }
}

$a = new aaa();
```